# campaign_details event is not logged in firebase

Tags: firebase, android-studio, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-firebase

I have created a campaign link and when i give

Bundle data = new Bundle();
data.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SOURCE,Applink.getQueryParameter("utm_source"));
data.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.MEDIUM,Applink.getQueryParameter("utm_medium"));
data.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CAMPAIGN,Applink.getQueryParameter("utm_campaign"));

```
    mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.CAMPAIGN_DETAILS, data);
```

But the event is not logged in firebase. have anyone faced similar issues? could you please let me know what im missing?

Comment: As per Firebase documentation, logging of Analytics takes upto 24hours to show up on firebase console. So if you have logged an event, you would have to wait for few hours to show up on the console.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40813565/firebase-event-not-logging-from-android-service

Comment: @KathanPatel, But Still i have not received in firebase its been a week since im trying this....

Comment: if i give the event_name anything else other than campaign_details it is logged in firebase. but if i give the event name as campaign_details it is not logged

Comment: I also have this problem. do you solved this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Seems that campaign_details events are only visible if you search through Big Query.
You can easily retrieve those events with the following query:

```
select * from `[tablename]` where event_name = 'campaign_details'
```